# jquery autocomplete does'nt show all the tags selected from the database

Tags: jquery, sql, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to use jquery autocomplete, the tags used in the autocomplete are extracted from a mysql database, the problem is that once the number of tags selected from the database overpass 500 (i tested it using LIMIT in SQL), the autocomplete stops working 
here is the SQL code :

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `tous_comptes`()
BEGIN
DECLARE nbr INT;
CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp(id int, libele varchar(255));
select count(*) into nbr from temp;
    IF nbr = 0 THEN
        insert into temp select idCD,libele from cd union select idcomptes,libele from comptes union select idsouscomptes,libele from souscomptes;
        select*from temp LIMIT 500;
    ELSE
        select*from temp LIMIT 500;
    END IF;

END
```

and here is the script that calls the the autocomplete function as well as the php file that generate the Json string

```js
$(function () {

        $.getJSON('autocomplete.php', function(data) {
             var com=new Array();
             var idcom= new Array();
             var i=0;
             $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                 com[i]=val.libele;
                 idcom[i]=val.id;
                 i++;

             });
                $("#compte").autocomplete({
                    source: idcom,
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {

                        for(var x=0; x<idcom.length;x++){
                          if(idcom[x] == ui.item.value){
                            $("#lblcompte").val(com[x]);

                          }
                        }

                    } 
                });
        }); 

    });
```

thanks in advance.